# FileZilla and IIS: GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated

Tags: ftp, ssl, iis, filezilla, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to connect to a VPS running Windows Server 2019 using Filezilla Client, but get the error

> GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

My Let's Encrypt certificate is set for domains: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), example.com, ftp.example.com
My IIS configuration is set to use this certificate on both the global level (see screenshot 1) and on the FTP level (see screenshot 2).
Screenshot 1
[image]
Screenshot 2
[image]
My FileZilla settings (using Default transfer mode, but I tried Active and Passive too with the same error)
[image]

Resulting in this logging in FileZilla:

```
Status: Resolving address of www.example.com
Status: Connecting to 15.200.12.44:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Error:  GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted".
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

**Connecting without SSL**
I tried to connect without SSL, so set FileZilla to Use `explicit FTP over TLS if available`.
And on my VPS I configured it to Allow SSL connections (and not require):
[image]
I then get the following notification but I AM able to connect:
[image]

My guess is it HAS to do with the certificate, but I don't know what.
I Googled for the error, and tried some debugging like recommended [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/gnutls_handshake-failed-the-tls-connection-was-non-properly-terminated-4175648907/) and [here](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/tls-handshake-failed/).

I also tried WinSCP, but still can't connect, so unlike some sites claim it's a FileZilla bug, I think I need to look for it on the server. But I'm lost on what to check now.

Comment: What error do you get with WinSCP?